# Why Gayatri Mantra is the king of all mantra?

Tags: gayatri-mantra

The Gayatri Mantra is called king of all Mantra. Chanting Gayatri Mantra every knowledge can be achieved.

Why is Gayatri Mantra so important? Who was the Gayatri Mantra given to first?

> ॐ भूर्भुव: स्व: तत्सवितुर्वरेण्यं । भर्गो देवस्य धीमहि, धीयो यो न:
>   प्रचोदयात् ।।

Comment: Lord Krishna in the Bhagavad Gita says `"Gayatri chandasam aham"` - (among the metres i am Gayatri). This itself is sufficient proof of this great mantra composed in the Gayatri metre(you can consider metre as something like a format). Please do search in Google for additional details. As of now, your question does not fit into the StackExchange format as this format does not encourage discussions..Please do ask this question in other forums for dicussions on this topic

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56106/discussion-on-question-by-anonymous-mohit-why-gayatri-mantra-is-the-king-of-all).

Comment: One of the saint, who attained Siddhi or Realisation of Gayatri Mantra, stated that the key to attaining Siddhi in a mantra lies in Anganyasa and Karanyasa, apart from proper uttering of the mantra proper.  It is not just keeping one's fingers in a particular spot in the body, but one should know how to activate the key shaktis lying at that centres.( https://ramanan50.wordpress.com/2014/08/28/nyasa-anga-and-kara-preparaion-for-pooja/ )  Otherwise it becomes a naama japa only. @Anonymous Mohit

Comment: I think this is a very wrong proposition. First of all, he says among all the Chandas (छंद) he's the Gãyatri Chanda (गायत्री छंद) *(why? - because it's the most melodious chanda?)* and not the specific **Gãyatri- Sãvitri Mantra**, which is more popularly called the Gãyatri Mantra by almost everyone these days. There can be several so called Mantras in the Vedas written in the Gãyatri Chanda. The question itself remain properly and unequivocally unanswered by anyone here though, as to why it's called the "King of Mantras" and actually where, which scriptures say so that this mantra is the King?

Answer (score 5):

Mother Gayatri is the GODDESS of **knowledge and virtues**. This mantra is specifically meant for Thapas (तपस; the highest of Tantras) as it increases the heat in the body burning up all muck at the physical level.

### Who gave Gayatri Mantra?

Sage Vishwamitra when he composed Rigveda, he put this mantra in it.

> Rig Veda 3.62.10 and Yajur Veda 36.3

Now there is no official record about how Vishwamitra got this mantra in Hindu scriptures.

Comment: I think "Gayatri" in Gayatri mantra refers to the Gayatri meter, it is actually devoted to Lord Savitr, the Sun God.

Answer (score 3):

Gayatri is called the mother of Vedas (or Vedamata). So, just like the mother is always the most superior, so is the Gayatri mantra among all the Vedic mantras. Therefore, this superiority is not like that of a king but it is like the superiority of the mother.

Quoting from the book [**Hindu Dharma** by Paramacharya](http://www.kamakoti.org/hindudharma/part17/chap10.htm):

> "Whoever sings is protected, " that is "Gayatri". "Gayantam trayate
>   yasmat Gayatri' tyabhidhiyate."
>
> "Sings" is not used here in the sense of singing a song. It means
>   intoning or chanting (the mantra) with affection and devotion. People
>   who chant the Gayatri in this manner are protected. While speaking
>   about this mantra the Vedas use these words : "Gayatrim Chandasam
>   mata". "Chandas" means the Vedas. **So Gayatri is the mother of all
>   Vedic mantras (that is the Vedas proclaim them so)**. It has
>   twenty-four aksaras (letters or syllables) and three feet, each foot
>   of eight syllables. That is why the mantra is called "Tripada
>   Gayatri". Each foot is the essence of a Veda. Thus Gayatri is the
>   essence of Rgveda, Yajurveda and Samaveda. The Atharvaveda has its own
>   Gayatri. To receive instruction in it you must have a second
>   upanayana.

We find a quote of Rishi Yajnavalkya regarding Gayatri being Veda Janani or the mother of Vedas in page4 of [this PDF](https://ambaa.org/pdf/gAyatrI_Worship.pdf):

> **Gayatri veda janani** gayatri papa nashini|
>  Gayatraya astu param
>   nasti divi cheha na pavanam ||
>
> Shri Yogavalkya Maharishi declares that Shri Gayatri is the mother of
>   all Vedas (in other words, the essence of all Vedas) and is the
>   destroyer of all sins; there is nothing beyond Shri Gayatri in both
>   Bhu loka and Deva loka

Another quote from Kurma Purana is also cited:

> **Gayatri veda janani** gayatri loka pavani|
>  Na gayatrayah param
>   japyam etat vigyana uchyate ||
>
> The above sloka from Kurma Puranam, while emphasizing that Shri
>   Gayatri Devi is the mother of all Vedas, declares beyond doubt that
>   Shri Gayatri purifies and sanctifies the Universe and there is no
>   other Mantra that is beyond Gaytri Mantram and it indeed is Vigyanam.

So, Gayatri mantra's supremacy comes from the fact that it is the mother of all Vedic mantras.

Comment: "Vedas use these words: Gayatrim Chandasam mata" -- where in the Vedas is this found? If it's the [Maha-Narayana Upanishad](http://www.astrojyoti.com/mahanarayanaupanishad-5.htm) it says: "XXXIV-1: May the boon-conferring discrimination Gayatri come to us (in order to instruct us about) the imperishable Brahman who is determined by the Vedanta. `May Gayatri, the mother of metres`, favour us with the Supreme just mentioned." I think 'mother of all `metres`' is different from 'mother of all `mantras`.'

Comment: I don't know where it is found. I was planning to answer this using directly a Vedic mantra but was unable to find that mantra yesterday @sv. And, Gayatri is definitely known as Vedamata. So, the approach is right. I just need to find a more convincing mantra/reference that's all.

Comment: Also to add to what @sv. had written, and more to the question, Gayatri mantra is not exactly referred to as _"The King of"_ all mantras. _"ChandasAm mAtA"_ doesn't directly mean king, and there is a different mantra for Lord Sri Nrsimha that is called _"mantra rAja"_. It is mentioned in the _"Nrsimha pUrva tApinya upanisad"_ (also known as _"nrsimha tApani upanisad"_ ). So from that reference the Nrsimha Mantra is clearly referred to as the King of mantras.

Answer (score 2):

In Ramayana it was mentioned that at dawn, Sri Rama and Lakshmana recited the Supreme Hymn at the behest of Sage Viswamitra.

> तस्य ऋषेः परम उदारम् वचः श्रुत्वा नृप नरोत्तमौ | स्नात्वा कृत उदकौ
>   वीरौ जेपतुः **परमम् जपम्** || १-२३-३
>
> On hearing the benign words of the sage those valorous and best ones
>   among men got up, bathed,and on offering water oblation they mediated upon the **supreme hymn**.

Though it was  mentioned  as Supreme Hymn, we can take it as **Gayatri mantra**, as it was [recited](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=kD84WlAtggkC&lpg=PA436&pg=PA331&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false) at twilight.

Vishvamitra was credited with authoring the 3rd Mandala of Rigveda, in which the Gayatri mantra was included.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vishvamitra

**However, it is not clearly mentioned whether this Viswamitra was the same Viswamitra, who was mentioned in the Bala Kanda of Ramayana.**

---

Now, the question part -  **Why is Gayatri Mantra so important?**

1. The Gāyatrī is dedicated to **Savitr**, a Vedic Sun deity. This is one aspect.  That was why recitation of this mantra used to be done by facing the Sun.
2. Another aspect is that in Vedic era, the inner meaning of the epithets like Indra, Agni, Surya, etc, used to denote the various forms of one Almighty God.

If we delve deep into SPIRITUALITY, we can find mention of experiencing **ABSOLUTE BLISS or  limitless light** in the final stages,  by sages like Sri Ramana Maharshi.

So the inner meaning of Sun or Surya is **ABSOLUTE BLISS or  limitless light**, if properly understood.

The recitation of **Savitr** mantra, which was formed in Gayatri metre in proper way will lead to  **ABSOLUTE BLISS or  limitless light**.

That is why it is SUPREME matra, as described by Sage Valmiki in Ramayana.

Comment: 'Though it was mentioned as Supreme Hymn, we can take it as Gayatri mantra, as it was recited at dawn' - instead of speculating better to cite commentaries on Ramayana. Example, check commentary on Sarga 22, verse 3 [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=kD84WlAtggkC&lpg=PA436&pg=PA331#v=onepage&q&f=false).

Comment: @sv.: I have checked the commentary on Sarga 22 at the link provided by you.  It also speculates. :-) It says " ....recitation of gayatri mantra was enjoined upon all the brahmanas", but did not provide authority.  Further, Sri Rama was a kshatriya, but not brAhmana.  The traditions at the time of penning the epic Ramayana might be different.

Comment: Better to use speculation/commentary of a scholar than our own :)