# Why is the Gayatri Mantra so important?Who is Gayatri Devi?What is Her relation with Lord Shiva?

Tags: vedas, mahabharata, shiva, gayatri-mantra, yajnavalkya

I have seen [this question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/3163/why-gayatri-mantra-is-the-king-of-all-mantra)
Someone had pointed out a quote of sage Yajnavalkya saying that Gayatri (Mantra) is the mother of the Vedas.

a)We know that the Vedas emerged from the four faces of Brahma.

b)The Shiva Sahasranama Stotram from Anushasana Parva says that Lord Shiva is **chaturvedasamanvitam**.(conglomeration of the 4 vedas.

So **is Gayatri devi actually name of Devi Saraswati?** And in light of **(b)**,won’t there be special emphasis on **Lord Shiva**,while mentioning about the Gayatri Mantra?

[Link of Shiva Sahasranama Stotram from where I heard (b)](https://youtu.be/YJ_K0JqPPpk)

Edit:

My question does not solely question the reason for the Gayatri Mantra’s supremacy,rather I’d like to know how things connect out with the respect to Lord Shiva (point b,above),and I’d also like to know whether Saraswati Devi and Gayatri Devi are two different names for the same deity,or is Gayatri Devi another goddess?
If she is another deity,is her worship popular?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why Gayatri Mantra is the king of all mantra?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/3163/why-gayatri-mantra-is-the-king-of-all-mantra)

Comment: Part of your question is more correct than other parts. The Gayatri is explained in Brihadaranyaka Upanishad V.xiv, (Chapter 5, section 14). you can read it here - https://www.holybooks.com/wp-content/uploads/Brihadaranyaka-Upanishad.pdf

Comment: @Vivikta I had seen some answers in that ,the one by Rickross was one reason I posted this question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Who is Goddess Gayatri? Is she another form of Saraswati or Saraswati in Parashakti form?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/43169/who-is-goddess-gayatri-is-she-another-form-of-saraswati-or-saraswati-in-parasha)

Comment: You should edit your question and make title like: 'How is the Gayatri Mantra connected to Lord Shiva?' something like this

Comment: @Archit,there are two answers that present things differently,so I am confused,in that link.

Comment: @Swami Vishwananda Swamiji,the part you referred gave a new  perspective.But the relation with Lord Shiva is not clarified.